# AUXtex is not showing preview in EMACS

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have just installed AUXtex and I follow the instruction on the manual very carefully, however, when I tried preview it shows an error icon instead of the preview image of the equation. What should I do to fix this?

I use:
Emacs 23
Ghostscript 9.01
texlive
ubuntu 11

My TEX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The solution to $\sqrt{x} = 5$ is $x=25$.

$A$
\end{document}
```

---

```
l.6 The solution to $
                     \sqrt{x} = 5$ is $x=25$.
Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
! Preview: Snippet 1 ended.(524466+157106x2122178).
<-><->

l.6 The solution to $\sqrt{x} = 5$
                                   is $x=25$.
[1]
! Preview: Snippet 2 started.
<-><->

l.6 The solution to $\sqrt{x} = 5$ is $
                                       x=25$.
! Preview: Snippet 2 ended.(422343+0x1903724).
<-><->

l.6 The solution to $\sqrt{x} = 5$ is $x=25$
                                            .
[2]
! Preview: Snippet 3 started.
<-><->

l.8 $
     A$
! Preview: Snippet 3 ended.(447828+0x491521).
<-><->

l.8 $A$
```

....
....

```
 Preview-DviPS finished at Fri Aug 12 22:52:32
Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``gs -dOutputFile\=\(_region_.prv/tmp10859AUf/pr1-\%d.pbm\) -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=pnmraw -r94.3276x94.1294''

Preview-Ghostscript finished at Fri Aug 12 22:52:32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - I had to compile auctex from cvs.  For whatever reason, preview doesn't work on 11.04 from the site's stable .tar.gz's.  Happy editing.

Comment: How do you compile auctex from cvs? Do I download it from cvs and compile? What command should I use?

Comment: `$ cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.savannah.gnu.org:/sources/auctex co auctex && cd auctex && make && sudo make install`

Comment: It said no make file found :(

Comment: Whoops - sorry!  You need to run
`sudo apt-get install texinfo autoconf automake`.   
Then, run `./autogen.sh` in the auctex directory.   
Finally, run  
`$ ./configure`  
`$ make`  
`$ sudo make install`